# How can I add space for tikz? I want add space between 1 and 2, also 2 and 3

Tags: tikz-trees

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{trees}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node {One}[edge from parent fork right, grow'=right, align=right]
        child { node(yongnian) {1}
               child {node(xixiang){11}
                   child {node{111}
                        child {node{111}
                          child {node{111}}}}
                   }
               child {node(xihui)[below of=xixiang]{222}}
                child {node(xifu)[below of=xihui]{222}}
                 child {node(xilu)[below of=xifu]{222}}
               }
        child { node(qingnian)[below of=yongnian] {2}
            child {node{Me}}
            child {node{My}}
            }   
        child { node (shengnian)[below of=qingnian] {3}
             child {node{Josh}}
             child {node{arah}}
            }   
     child { node(fengnian)[below of=shengnian] {4}
             child {node{sh}}
             child {node{arah}}
            }           
    ;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: Thank you. But I cannot understand.

Answer (score 2):

Add appropriate distances for `sibling distance` like

```
level 1/.style={sibling distance=1in},
level 2/.style={sibling distance=1cm},
```

Further, you won't need all those `below of=` stuff here. As a side note with `positioning` library it should be `below = of`.

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{trees}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
level 1/.style={sibling distance=1in},
level 2/.style={sibling distance=1cm},
grow'=right, align=right
  ]
    \node {One}[edge from parent fork right]
        child { node(yongnian) {1}
               child {node(xixiang){11}
                   child {node{111}
                        child {node{111}
                          child {node{111}}}}
                   }
               child {node(xihui){222}}
                child {node(xifu){222}}
                 child {node(xilu){222}}
               }
        child { node(qingnian) {2}
            child {node{Me}}
            child {node{My}}
            }
        child { node (shengnian) {3}
             child {node{Josh}}
             child {node{arah}}
            }
     child { node(fengnian) {4}
             child {node{sh}}
             child {node{arah}}
            }
    ;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If I want the distance between 1 and 2 is three cm, 3 and 4 is five cm.

Comment: @YumingFeng Your wish may not be granted ;-)

Comment: @YumingFeng Changing distances as you request is not possible. BTW thanks are better conveyed here by up voting and accepting. Please refer to [How do you accept an answer](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1852/how-do-you-accept-an-answer)